# sysadmin script off topic?

Tags: discussion

I don't get it.  At least on stackoverflow homework is [fine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277881/262852), so that seems irrelevant for askubuntu as well.

Why is this [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1001469/45156) closed?

Seems like a fairy standard admin type question.  Presumably bash scripts should be on stackoverflow instead?

Notably, **not** a generic programming question:

> ...and generic programming questions on Stack Overflow.

*based on the accepted answer, and comments, this is just specific to this one q.  I'd already researched whether hw is acceptable as a q.*

Comment: Also relevant: [Allow “homework” questions?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/2224/507051) and [Ask Ubuntu's stance on Homework-type questions](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/12414/507051).

Comment: My view is that a question that **stems** from homework is fine. If you can't solve it, feel free to ask. But this is a cut'n'paste of the text, with **no** attempts at solving it!

Comment: That's my take.  Also, if the HW q is so simple as to BE a valid q, then...well, there's just no downside.  (Distinction being a larger project.)

Comment: There's no valid reason to close that question or policy that supports closing it. Shell scripting is on topic here. I've tried to reopen it but reviewers voted to leave closed

Comment: @Zanna ditto.  I suppose you could downvote it as low-quality, nothing attempted.  Or, mebbe, mebbe, too large of a question.

Comment: yeah, I guess one could argue for "too broad" but I wouldn't agree with that because it's a single task. Closing questions based on our idea about OP's behaviour or attitude just doesn't accord with the purpose of the site. If the question is useful and answerable, it shouldn't be closed or downvoted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I completely agree the fact that a question is related to homework is no valid reason for closure.

***HOWEVER***

Although we like to think we are rational human beings, we rarely are, and decisions are easily made on emotion. 
Reading the header of your question, it makes the impression of someone, coming home from school, taking a beer from the fridge and throwing his or her question on the site to have the homework done.

I know I have voted to close questions like that, and I can understand why people do. So my advice would be: if you are trying to find a solution to a homework related question, write in your own words what you tried and where you get stuck. No one will object to a sincere question for help like that.

Comment: I would just add that it would be preferable to down-vote the q on that basis rather than close it.  Or, even better, since, I think, that was this persons first question ***EVER***, edit it a bit.  But I take your point.